# Segmentation fault is thrown when using Metal (Mac OS X 10.15.6)

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

I am trying to learn Metal through the Apple documentation. So far, I have finished writing an application that calculates the square root of 4096 random numbers. However, when I run it through the terminal, it immediately throws a segmentation fault.

Output:

```c
Segmentation fault: 11
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

So far, I have tried inserting `std::cout`s almost everywhere in the code and I have found the problem to be with the function that generates the random numbers (`generateRandomFloatData(id<MTLBuffer> buffer)`).

When I tried to print out the address of the input buffer, I got this output:

```
0x0
Segmentation fault: 11
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Weirdly, it prints out the address of a NULL pointer.

More testing revealed that changing the function to input a char pointer correctly outputs an address `0x7ffee8bd8620` pointing to the string.

Is there a problem in my code?

```
//
//  main.mm
//  MetalComputeCPP
//
//  Created by [] on 5/1/21.
//  Copyright © 2021 thng. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <Metal/Metal.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <chrono>
const unsigned int arrayLength = 1 << 12;
const unsigned int bufferSize = arrayLength * sizeof(float);
void generateRandomFloatData(id<MTLBuffer> buffer) {
    std::cout << ((float*)buffer.contents) << "\n";
    float* dataPtr = ((float*)buffer.contents);
    for (unsigned long index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
    {
        dataPtr[index] = (float)((rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX))*10);
        std::cout << dataPtr[index] << "\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    id<MTLDevice> _mDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    
    
    NSError* error = nil;
    id<MTLLibrary> defaultLibrary = [_mDevice newDefaultLibrary];
    id<MTLFunction> SqrtFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"SqrtArray"];
    
    id<MTLComputePipelineState> _mSqrtFunctionPSO = [_mDevice newComputePipelineStateWithFunction: SqrtFunction error:&error];
    id<MTLCommandQueue> _mCommandQueue = _mDevice.newCommandQueue;
    
    id<MTLBuffer> _mBufferA = [_mDevice newBufferWithLength:bufferSize options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
    id<MTLBuffer> _mBufferResult = [_mDevice newBufferWithLength:bufferSize options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
    
    MTLSize gridSize = MTLSizeMake(arrayLength, 1, 1);
    NSUInteger threadGroupSize = _mSqrtFunctionPSO.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup;
    if (threadGroupSize > arrayLength)
    {
        threadGroupSize = arrayLength;
    }
    MTLSize threadgroupSize = MTLSizeMake(threadGroupSize, 1, 1);
    
    generateRandomFloatData(_mBufferA);
    std::cout << "Generated random float data.\n";
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = _mCommandQueue.commandBuffer;
    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    [computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:_mSqrtFunctionPSO];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:_mBufferA offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:_mBufferResult offset:0 atIndex:1];
    [computeEncoder dispatchThreads:gridSize
    threadsPerThreadgroup:threadgroupSize];
    [computeEncoder endEncoding];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    [commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    uint64_t time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count();
    
    
    float* a = ((float*)_mBufferA.contents);
    float* result = ((float*)_mBufferResult.contents);
    bool err = false;
    for (unsigned long index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
    {
        if (abs(result[index] - (float)sqrt(a[index])) > 0.0001) err = true;
        std::cout << "√" << a[index] << (err ? " != " : " = ") << result[index] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << time << " nanoseconds\n";
    printf("Compute results as expected\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
//
//  File.metal
//  MetalComputeCPP
//
//  Created by [] on 5/1/21.
//  Copyright © 2021 thng. All rights reserved.
//

#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
kernel void SqrtArray(device const float* inA,
                     device float* outB,
                     uint ind [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    //(x^n-k)' = (nx^(n-1))
    //f(x0)/f'(x0)
    outB[ind] = 0.1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        outB[ind] = outB[ind]-((outB[ind]*outB[ind]-inA[ind])/(outB[ind]*2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer` in `generateRandomFloatData`  is `nil` because `_mBufferA` is `nil`.

`_mBufferA` is `nil` because `_mDevice` is `nil`.

`MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` returns `nil` because (from [MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/1433401-mtlcreatesystemdefaultdevice?language=occ))

> In macOS, in order for the system to provide a default Metal device object, you must link to the CoreGraphics framework. You usually need to do this explicitly if you are writing apps that don't use graphics by default, such as command line tools.

Your previous question:

> Why does Metal not work when run via the Terminal but is fine when run through Xcode?

In Xcode `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` returns on my Mac

> _mDevice: <CaptureMTLDevice: 0x10050bbb0> -> <MTLDebugDevice: 0x10050aae0> -> <MTLIGAccelDevice: 0x1031c8000>
> name = Intel HD Graphics 4000

In Terminal `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` returns

> _mDevice: <MTLIGAccelDevice: 0x7f9c32f17000>
> name = Intel HD Graphics 4000

Apparenlty Xcode wraps the device in a debugging device, which has the side effect of fixing the issue.